# angularJS when to use curly braces when to use quotation

Tags: angularjs

In angularJS sometimes I'm using curly braces sometimes I can just put it in double quote. Take the following `li` tag for example:

```
<ul ng-repeat="question in questionModel.questionaire">
[...]
  <ul ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
    <li><input type="radio" 
           ng-click="questionModel.handleChange(answer)" 
           ng-model = "question.answered" 
           value={{answer}} 
           name={{$parent.$index}} required>
        {{answer}}
    </li>
```

I coded it with trial and error, I never sure if I should be using {{}} or double quotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has some pre-defined directives that you use in your template like ng-model, ng-show, ng-if and so on. For these you can simply assign values in double quotes

For the ones which are not a part of angular like 'value', placeholder, name etc. if you want to pass data from controller you will have to use curly braces (or whatever symbols you are using for interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces handle the interpolation of a value to a string.  If you are using a directive that requires a string value, then you should use curly braces.

At all other times, you're omitting the curly braces.  This is because value passed to the directive is either a function reference (as in your `ngClick` directive), or is an object (as in your `ngModel` directive).

Comment: Do you they also take care of HTML escaping the output of the expression? Rahul's answer is still valid - you **need** to use them when not given as a directive if you expect Angular to know it needs to interpret that piece of code.